# How to sort out this error " A ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest occurred in "

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

> A ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest occurred in schools#student_info:
>
> Security warning: an embedded  tag on another site requested
> protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and
> disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin
> JavaScript embedding.

please solve this error

Comment: We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted. It may be worth spending the time reading the [How to Ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

As it is already said - more context is required. 
As of the issue itself, it appears when, for example, you are trying to make an AJAX call from web_site_a.com page towards web_site_b.com server. If this is the case, check this [gem](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) for a solution.